# return value coming as undefined in Cypress Javascript

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new in cypress, I have created a generic function which is checking the count of rows in cypress and returning the count. I have used for loop, and returning the count under the chain. This function is correctly calculating count but if I call under the second function I am getting as undefined or null
**I have defined a global variable and below generic function where I am trying to return the count
Calling under second function, in which I am getting** **rowcount_val** as **undefined**

```js
let rowcount_val = 0

function checkrowcount() {
    var count = 0;
    var val = ""
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        cy.get(".rt-tbody>div:nth-child(" + i + ")>div>div:nth-child(1)").then((
            e) => {
            val = e.text();
            if (val.length > 1) {
                count++
            }
        })
    }
    cy.then(() => {
        return cy.log("count*" + count).then(() => {
            return count;
        })
    })
}
When('click on Add button', function() {
    cy.then(() => {
        rowcount_val = checkrowcount();
        cy.log("rowcountvalue is ******" + rowcount_val)
    })
})
```

Comment: `checkrowcount` has no `return` statement. It always returns `undefined`. Asynchronous code using Callbacks and Promises is one of the fundamental features of JS that you need to learn the basics of.

Answer (score 5):

You are overriding the global variable with an undefined return value from the function.

To mkae it work, change

```js
rowcount_val = checkrowcount();
```

to

```js
checkrowcount();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but the value it suppose to return I want to save in a variable and use further...how do I store in the variable?

Comment: This changes the code so that instead of updating the global variable with the return value, it throws the return value away. For a question about getting the return value, that doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: This is valid, the variable is already updated by closure. You shouldn't be using both closure and return value - at the minimum it's confusing code.